# Json to form a navigation menu

Tags: json, aem, jcr

I have a property in the jcr which has a data like below

```
{
    "headerNavTitle":"HEADER NAV TITLE",
    "headerNavLink":"HEADER NAV LINK",
    "subMenuTitle":["{\"subTitle\":\"SUBTITLE\",
            \"subMenuLinks\":[\"{\\\"navLinkTitle\\\":\\\"NAV LINK TITLE1\\\",
             \\\"navLink\\\":\\\"NAV LINK1\\\"}\",
             \"{
             \\\"navLinkTitle\\\":\\\"NAV LINK TITLE2\\\",
             \\\"navLink\\\":\\\"NAV LINK2\\\
            "}\"]
    }"]
}
```

I would like to display it a navigation menu, please provide your input, if someone has done the similar implementation. thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't valid JSON unless you're escaping those newlines...